# is check field with rel value checked

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to see if a selector is check. trick is - it is a class with a rel value where both needs to match.

Tried this:

```
    $('.checking').click(function(){
      var right_group_id = $(this).attr('rel');
      if($('.checking[rel='+right_group_id+'] :checked')){
            $('.'+right_group_id).attr('checked', 'checked');
      } else {
          $('.'+right_group_id).removeAttr('checked');
      }
    });
```

and the input box

```
<input type=checkbox class='checking' rel='".$_array["group_id"]."' title='Click to check group'>
```

how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code this is help you.

```
$('.checking').onchange(function(){
  var right_group_id = $(this).attr('rel');
  if($('.checking[rel='+right_group_id+']').prop('checked')){
        $('.'+right_group_id).prop('checked',true);
  } else {
      $('.'+right_group_id).prop('checked',false);
  }
});
```

Comment: $('.checking').on("change", function(){
    var right_group_id = $(this).attr('rel');
    if($('.checking[rel='+right_group_id+']').prop('checked')){
          $('.'+right_group_id).prop('checked',true);
    } else {
        $('.'+right_group_id).prop('checked',false);
    }
  });

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 $('.checking').click(function(){
      var right_group_id = $(this).attr('rel');
      if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
            $('.'+right_group_id).attr('checked', 'checked');
      } else {
          $('.'+right_group_id).removeAttr('checked');
      }
    });
```